# Uniform convergence for the Fourier series of $\alpha$-Hölder periodic functions and continuous bounded variation periodic functions.

Tags: fourier-series

In the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012365/how-to-show-for-alpha-in-0-1-any-f-in-c-alpha0-1-sim-has-a-fouri) it is proved that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a $\alpha$-Hölder $2\pi$-periodic function, then the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly to $f$.

In the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082977/if-f-in-bv-mathbbt-cap-c-mathbbt-does-the-fourier-series-of-f-conver) it is proved that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous bounded variation $2\pi$-periodic function, then the Fourier series of $f$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Note that since the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for every $\alpha<1$ and differentiable nowhere (hence not of bounded variation), and since $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is absolutely continuous in $[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$ but not $\alpha$-Hölder continuous for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$, the first result doesn't imply directly the second and vice versa.

> Can be both theorems be viewed as particular results of a theorem for a class of functions that contains both continuous bounded variation periodic functions and $\alpha$-Hölder periodic functions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show for $\alpha\in (0,1)$, any $f\in C^\alpha([0,1]/{\sim})$ has a Fourier series $S_nf$ uniformly converging to $f$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012365/how-to-show-for-alpha-in-0-1-any-f-in-c-alpha0-1-sim-has-a-fouri)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll modify the question accordingly citing your question and leaving only the second part

Comment: Of course there's no such thing as a proof that the answer is no, but I tend to think the answer's no, just because if there were such a result I suspect I would have heard about it - people would prove the two results you mention as special cases of the general result, which they don't, as far as I've ever seen.